# How can I customize the appearance of scroll bars in Kate?

Tags: text-editor, kate

Although Kate (the editing software) allows users to customize the look and feel of most of the items, but I've not been able to find a way to customize the appearance of its scroll bars. With a dark color scheme in use, the bright color of the scroll bars starts to shine in the eyes and becomes slightly disruptive. Any assistance with customizing the appearance of the Kate's scroll bars would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding to that, I'd like a fat scroll bar in Kate, with a document miniature like you can get in the Sublime Text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Gnome, KDE or some other desktop environment?

Since Kate is a KDE program it uses KDE widgets and KDE's theme/colour settings. If you use KDE you can change these in the system settings. If you use Gnome you probably have to install KDE's system settings program (I believe this is simply called “systemsettings”) and configure it there.

Comment: Although I am not using the editor any more, but thanks for the response. I stopped checking for the responses after a few days, hence the delay. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbars in Kate follow the KDE color scheme. Currenty, the scrollbar colors are not configurable separately.

As of KDE 4.10, Kate's scrollbar can be turned into a minimap, see [here for a screenshot](http://kate-editor.org/2012/11/03/busy-katekdevelop-sprint-results-in-mini-map/). This minimap follows the background colors that are configured by the Kate color scheme, so you can change it to your liking, see for [instance also here](http://linuxlibrary.org/kate-text-editor-gains-mini-map-scrolling-ability/).